# how can i make a list inside a function global?

Tags: python, list, global, local-variables

in this function, I have a list I want to make global and allow access to outside the function:

```
def get_data():
    d = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ)
    feed = pickle.loads(d)

    number_authorized = []
    for q in feed:
        number_authorized.append(q[0]) 
    number_authorized.sort()
```

This `number_authorized` list changes each time the function `get_data()` is called.
I want the global `number_authorized` list to change according to the changes inside the function.

How can I allow access to the list and its values outside the function?
Do I have to state `global number_authorized` every time I try to change or access the list's values?

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me!!! :)

Comment: If you simply *declare* the list outside the function instead of inside the function, it would already work just fine.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want to plant the list's values in an OptionMenu widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare that:

```
def get_data():
    d = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ)
    feed = pickle.loads(d)

    global number_authorized #declaration

    number_authorized = []
    for q in feed:
        number_authorized.append(q[0]) 
    number_authorized.sort()
```

Comment: when I try to access the number_authorized outside the function like this:                `global number_authorized`              
`print number_authorized` it gives me this error: `NameError: global name 'number_authorized' is not defined`

Comment: @mimiquarantine you have to call the fucntion first. then use print(). you you call the fucntion only, the code inside it gets excecuted (ie, it only then is defined as global)